# Git - Sync local repository between a usb stick and a computer

Tags: git, synchronization

I have a laptop, where repository A, which reside in the home directory, under an example name `test`.

I have commited a couple of things, namely text file, etc into that same repository.
The usb stick, which is plugged in the laptop, is automatically mounted using a cronjob.

What are the ways to sync the repository between those two local endpoint (they do not face internet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside repository A, add the repository on the USB stick as a remote:

```
git remote add usbstick /mnt/...
```

Then you’ll be able to push your changes:

```
git push usbstick master
```

(if your branch name is `master`).

If you make changes to the USB stick elsewhere, you can pull them using `git pull`. If you make changes in both repositories, you’ll need to merge them, or rebase one on top of the other.

Comment: any way to get them to automatically sync if a change is made to either of them? (with either a cronjob or something like `inotifywatch` i presume?)

Comment: That depends what you mean by synchronise automatically. I’m not aware of anything readily available that will fully synchronise two git repositories automatically, *i.e.* ensure they end up in some common state. I use [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) and [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) for file synchronisation, but for git repositories I only automate `git fetch` (which ensures that remote content is available locally, but doesn’t have to deal with merges).

Comment: I see. I did planned to use this method with git-annex, though i never tried syncthing. I'll check it out, thanks!